# WooCommerce add to cart not working on mobile site or loading description

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hey probably sounds like a repeat questions. Tried all the solutions on stackoverflow but seem not to get the answer.

www.sextoyswizard.com (no adult nudity on this site)

Only does not run on mobile . You cant add anything to the cart nor click anywhere on that page to load description for instance.

Comment: Does problem occurred after any modification? OR after move to new server? or recently any new plugin installed?

Answer (score 0):

There's a container that overlaps your div with id="container". It looks as though it's your search container that exists at the bottom underneath the product options.

```
<div id="container">
  ....
</div>
<div id="secondary" class="" role="complementary">
  ....
</div>
```

You need to either move this div somewhere or remove it. So you'll have to set up your markup to take that into consideration.

For example, in css I added:

```
#secondary {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This kept the search form in the bottom.